# Large zip files served appear on client as 0 byte files

Tags: php, apache

I am serving up files via php through apache.  I'm having a problem where relatively large files (I'm working on a 350 MB zip) appear to be downloading all the way but on the client they appearing as a zero byte file.

Only one file is being served at a time and the only files served are zip files.  I'm having no problem with smaller files. (eg 70MB).  I've bumped up the time and memory limits to seemingly overly generous values (both in the php and the php.ini).  After about 20-30 seconds it appears to be done downloading, but in both Firefox and Chrome, there's no good result:

Firefox: no error message.  Dialog pops up to save or Open.  It saves as a zero byte file.  If told to open, winzip provides an error message that the file is broken.
Chrome: After about 20 seconds, it says "This webpage is not available" and shows .  It also says "Error code: ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH"

I don't know if this means anything, but I've looks at the network activity in Chrome's dev tools and the 70MB file's shows as (cancelled) under Status after its been served correctly.

Here's the php code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');  //also see memory_limit in php.ini
set_time_limit(60);  //also max_execution_time in php.ini
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); //also tried application/zip
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.basename($fileLocation));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileLocation));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($fileLocation);
exit;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Downloading 350 MB in 60 seconds (what is your time limit) turns into 5,8 MB per second. Sounds challenging to me. Just change your time limit:

```
set_time_limit(60*30);  //also max_execution_time in php.ini
```

Comment: I think I bumped it to 600 seconds in a later test, but even with 60 seconds, it's finishing after around 20-30 seconds.

Comment: usually things like that happen on timing and/or size settings. You need to check all your timing and cache size settings on php, apache, local browser. Also check your available memory and constraints of proxies (if you use any). A structured debug process also involves checking/configuring of (error)logs of php and apache. looking at http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php says: "readfile() will not present any memory issues, even when sending large files, on its own."